# Mapping JSON data to model and back in MVC 4

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Pardon any misspeaking I may do. I am just learning asp.net c#, OOP, and MVC 4.

I am using the Annotator plugin on my site and I am trying to store and retrieve the results from a data base. When a new annotation is created it sends information like this to the controller.

```
 {
      "text":"asdas sd a dasd as dasd",
      "ranges":
       [{
             "start":"/div/p[3]",
             "startOffset":195,
             "end":"/div/p[3]",
             "endOffset":532
       }],
       "quote":"Some quote that was selected.",
       "UserID":"1",
       "ProjectDocID":"1"
 }
```

Now, I hoped something like this would load all the data into a nice easy object.

```
 // GET: /Annotation/Create

    public ActionResult Create(Comment comment)
    {
        db.Comments.Add(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(comment);
    }
```

The model I had looked like this (and I am change it however it needs to be changed).

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectDocID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string text { get; set; }
    public string Annotation { get; set; }
    public string quote { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public string startOffset { get; set; }
    public string endOffset { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CommentVote> CommentVote { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CommentReply> CommentReply { get; set; }

    public ProjectDoc ProjectDoc { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; } 
}
```

What do I need to do to get the data from the server and map it to the model. I also need to be able to send it back in the format at the top so the plugin understands it when it asks for it from the Details action in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way to do it or not, but it lets me store it in the database and that's all that matter for the moment. I updated my model as follows.

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectDocID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string quote { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CommentVote> CommentVote { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CommentReply> CommentReply { get; set; }
    public ProjectDoc ProjectDoc { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public List<ranges> ranges { get; set; }
}
public class ranges {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public string startOffset { get; set; }
    public string endOffset { get; set; }


}
```

This matches the JSON object I am sending in to the controller with Ajax. Once it matches exactly the controller action above works.